# Preview Markup Options for Shape Fill

Tags: macos, preview

Working on a Mac Desktop OS Sierra, want to use Preview to markup a pdf, but need the filled rectangle to be translucent, not opaque.  I only see fill, and no fill options on the menu.

Is this possible to achieve and what steps might work?

Answer (score 1):

After creating your rectangle you can choose the color picker, then Show Colors. That gives you an opacity slider.

Here you can see I've given it a purple tint.

[image]